# android wait for a function

Tags: java, android

I have two classes A and B. I am in class A and I called a function in class B, in which a button is initialized. When the button is clicked, the value of x becomes true (which was initially false). Before executing next statement in class A, the value of x in class B should be true.
I tried B.wait(), but it is returning exception.
Anyway to do it?

Comment: consider posting actual code so we can better understand the problem. is Class A an Activity and class B a fragment?

Comment: Class A is Activity and class B is CustomGridView.. I am creating buttons in the gridview using gridAdapter in class B.

Comment: Create methods in class A that get called in the buttons onClick method. Be careful about using `wait` on UI threads because that will look like the app is hanging to the user (and android will prompt the user to kill any app that hangs for 5 seconds) I still recommend editing your post with actual code.

Comment: Is it necessary that button should be clicked to set x to true? May be you can set it true after initializing your button.

Comment: Using AsyncTack will help you, try it. find some tutorial and do the change by your need.

Answer (score 0):

you can use AsyncTask class.
in pre-execute function, initialize x and button or whatever and in post-execute and do whatever you want to.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add something like this:

```
while (B.x == false) {
    try { Thread.sleep(50); } catch (Exception e) {}
    // Sleeping is necessary to prevent high CPU usage
}
```

Anyway, you should never use this in the `UI Thread` because it might result in an `ANR` (**A**pplication **n**ot **r**esponding)